# Is there a way to sync payment amount into credit card terminals such as verifone vx520 or Ingenico ict250 from windows 10?

Tags: payment, credit-card, point-of-sale, pos

I am working on a project where I need to send an amount to a credit card terminal such as verifone vx520 or Ingenico ict250.

If it was from Windows 10, would there be a way to communicate with the terminals to show an amount on the terminal screen?
(we are trying to avoid manual input on the terminal)

If it is not possible to send an amount to either verifone vx520 or Ingenico ict250, are there any other terminals that can accumplish this?
If so, it would be very helpful if you can also show me their API documents.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The device you want to use is called CAT (Credit Authorization Terminal) in the UnifiedPOS specification.

Get the specification PDF from this page and refer to the specification from page 281.
[Document -- retail/17-07-32 (UnifiedPOS Retail Peripheral Architecture, Version 1.14.1)](https://www.omg.org/cgi-bin/doc?retail/2017-07-32)

However, this device specification has been standardized at the request from the Japanese market and is likely not implemented in countries other than Japan.

Perhaps neither Verifone nor Ingenico provide control of CAT devices OPOS/POS for.NET/JavaPOS.
It seems that other vendors do not have it.

Vendors such as Verifone and Ingenico have their own developer sites and SDKs.
Also, vendors will have information on ISVs that use them to provide applications/solutions with the features you want.

Register to a site such as the following to get information on SDKs and applications/solutions.

[Verifone Developper Central](https://developer.verifone.com/docs/overview/platform)
[Retail Solutions](https://www.verifone.com/en/us/retail-solutions)

[Ingenico ePayments Developer hub](https://epayments.developer-ingenico.com/)
[POS Solutions](https://www.ingenico.com/pos-solutions)